# Using Visio viewer to show macro enabled drawings

Tags: visio

I'm trying to view a published drawing with Visio viewer that has macros (the target machine does not have Visio installed - just the viewer). The macros are not being run - is there any way using Viewer to allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Visio Viewer does not support macros.